# C# Regex to match attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to extract the value of 'value'

I got this regular expression to [work on regexstorm.com](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3C%3Dvalue%3D%27%29%5B%5E%27%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%27%29&i=%22%7BAboveText%20tagtype%3D%27h1%27%20%20value%3D%27this%20is%20the%20value%20i%20want%27%7D%22&o=i)

but in my code i get 0 matches..

```
string textstring = "{AboveText tagtype='h1' value='this is the value i want'}";

Regex attributeRegex = new Regex("\b(?<=value=\')[^']+(?=')", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var attributes = attributeRegex.Matches(textString);
```

can anyone help?